# How to set user agent for UiWebView in Xamarin.Forms iOS app

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am currently setting the user agent of the UIWebView within my HybridWebViewRenderer in my iOS project in my Xamarin.Forms app.

It does work but only at first, subsequent web requests do not have the UserAgent.

I am setting the UserAgent as follows in OnElementChanged in HybridWebViewRenderer and my understanding is that this will be called once when the WebView is created.

```
   public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, UIWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            UIWebView agentWebView = new UIWebView();
            var userAgent = agentWebView.EvaluateJavascript("navigator.userAgent");
            userAgent += "MyApp";
            NSDictionary dictionary = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(NSObject.FromObject(userAgent), NSObject.FromObject("UserAgent"));
            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults(dictionary);
            agentWebView.ShouldStartLoad += HandleStartLoad;
            base.SetNativeControl(agentWebView);
            agentWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(e.NewElement.Uri.ToString())));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the exact same code, but I do it in the constructor rather than the OnElementChanged event.